# Count no Firebird 3.0 Bigint X FIrebird 2.5 Integer

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, firebird

No meu sistema, após a migração do `Firebird 2.5` para o `3.0`, muitos relatórios e outras funções começaram a dar problema informando que o esperado era `Integer` e o atual é `LargeInt`.
Dei uma olhada e vi q algumas pesquisas com `count` no `3.0` retornam uma coluna `Bigint`, enquanto no `2.5` retorna uma coluna `Integer`.

Para resolver da maneira q conheço, teria que fazer um `cast` em tudo que está dando erro, testei e funcionou, porém é um sistema grande, vai dar muiiiiito trabalho.

Alguém sabe alguma maneira de resolver isso, no próprio `Firebird`? alguma configuração, ou coisa assim?

Comment: Não ficou claro pra mim. Você faz um select count, e atribui esse valor a uma variável do tipo Integer. Isso em Firebird 3 dá erro ?

Comment: Não @VictorZanella... No simples `Open` do `dataset` é gerado o erro. Isso porque o `dataset` já possui os `TFields` adicionados, porém ao ser aberto, o campo vem em outro formato... Por isso a mensagem: *Esperado Integer, encontrado LargeInt*.

Comment: Difícil afirmar isso @Andrey. A pergunta esta focada em Firebird. Vou esperar o sounobre responder. ;)

Comment: Tranquilo @VictorZanella... Posso estar errado, mas como já passei por esse problema, me parece óbvio o problema.. mas vamos aguardar o sounobre

Comment: VictorZanella é exatamente o que o @Andrey disse, se eu adicionar novamente no dataset, vou ficar com o incidente ao contrário, dando erro no Firebird 2.5... na verdade estou procurando alguma configuração milagrosa que me salve de fazer um cast em várias partes do código....rsrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, se você estiver usando o `FireDAC`, há uma solução bem plausível.
Chama-se `MapRules`, mais informações você encontra nesse [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Data_Type_Mapping_(FireDAC)).

Com essa tecnologia, você consegue dizer ao sistema para tratar um campo `LargeInt` como `Integer` ou vice-versa.
Uso esse recurso no nosso sistema para fazer a compatibilidade entre bancos diferentes.

Comment: Amigo, não estou usando o Firedac.... to no delphi 7 usando o unidac...

Comment: O unidac também possui essa solução. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

No Firebird acredito não ter como configurar isso, veja no [Release Notes pag. 89](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/Firebird-3.0.0-ReleaseNotes.pdf). Infelizmente neste caso você terá que fazer o cast ou se estiver utilizando os fields adicionados na qry ou clientdataset acho que é só remover o field e adicionar novamente que o driver mapeia o tipo corretamente.

Te indico a ler o livro [Guia de Migração para o Firebird 3](http://www.firebase.com.br/guiafb3.php), tem umas dicas bem legais.

Comment: Obrigado... Pensei q tivesse algo a fazer pra não dar muito trabalho... fazer o cast em tudo vai dar um trabalho danado... e ñ posso remover o field, pq ainda tem clientes usando a versão 2.5...

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar o problema de compatibilidade, altere a linha na query `count()` para `cast(count() as integer)`. Irá funcionar perfeitamente na versão 2.5 e 3.

Answer (score -2):

O problema é devido ao dialeto que você está utilizando, provavelmente o 3 para versões com total compatibilidade com o interbase é bom você utilizar o 1 assim ele trunca o big int e não aparecerá aqueles caracteres de estouro de memória(?,=).
Um link explicando melhor o que eu quero dizer
https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/isql-dialects.html