# Zeos: Erro de diferenças de tipos em bancos de dados diferentes

Tags: delphi, zeos

Tenho um sistema feito em Delphi 7 que pode ser conectado tanto no MySql como no Firebird.. Tenho um arquivo de configurações onde informo o host, banco, usuário, senha, porta e o protocolo do Zeos que indica o tipo de banco. Está abrindo o banco MySql sem problemas, mas quando coloco as configurações para acessar Firebird em localhost, concta mas ao abrir as tabelas está dando erro de tipos diferentes dos campos. No caso o primeiro campo que já dá um erro é um campo Float mas o Zeos está interpretando como Integer. Alguém pode me dar uma idéia do que pode estar acontecendo?
obg!

Comment: Você está usando as mesmas tabelas para abrir o Firebird e o Mysql? A não ser que os dois campos sejam extremamentes iguais pode ocorrer esse erro. Eu já fiz essa mesma conexão que esta tentando e usei um conjunto de tabelas para usar o Firebird e outro para o Mysql.

Comment: Peço que por favor edite sua pergunta colocando o código e organizando melhor o seu problema.

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta possa ser a solução que você precisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170407/49822